# SpringBoot: create a request factory for proxy GET Request

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to make a GET request to another API. I need to pass a proxy as well. I tried to implement a REST template request factory, but i get a connection timeout. Here is my controller:

```
@RestController
public class AuthenticateController {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();

        Proxy proxy= new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost", proxyport));
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(3000);
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Value("${resources.authenticate}")
    private String authServiceUrl;

    @GetMapping("/authenticate")
    public AuthenticateRto authenticateUser(@RequestParam("api_key") String apiKey) {

        UriComponentsBuilder authenticateUrlBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(authServiceUrl)
                .queryParam("api_key", apiKey);
        return restTemplate.getForObject(authenticateUrlBuilder.toUriString(), AuthenticateRto.class);
    }
}
```

I am not sure if the proxy is set when making the call.

Comment: Why did you declare an autowired variable `restTemplate`? Can you not use `restTemplate()` method instead?

Comment: Thanks Boris works

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be to use [constructor injection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection.html).

Declare `RestTemplate` bean in a configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
    Proxy proxy= new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost", proxyport));
    requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(3000);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(3000);
    return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
  }

}
```

And then use a constructor injection to obtain the required `RestTemplate` bean:

```java
@RestController
public class AuthenticateController {

  private final RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public AuthenticateController(RestTemplate RestTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
  }

  // rest of the controller's logic
}
```

Note that you can omit the `@Autowired` since `AuthenticateController` has one constructor.